# Letter Environment : Justice!

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, letters, letterhead, addresses

I'm looking at [this](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/letters.htm), and I'm wondering how I can get `Mr. John Doe \\ 2345 Jones St. \\ Oakland, CA  91123` to be right justified in this `letter` environment:

```
 \begin{letter}{Mr. John Doe \\ 2345 Jones St. 
      \\ Oakland, CA  91123}
   ...
 \end{letter}
```

Thank you.

---

This is specifically dealing with the question found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117790/letterhead-how-to-position-images-in-top-left-corner-revisit).

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that sets up the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @PeterGrill See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117790/letterhead-how-to-position-images-in-top-left-corner-revisit).

Comment: Whoever marked this a duplicate should explain their reasoning please.

Comment: @TyquanPesik: So I guess you're bound to the `letter` document class? The solutions in the linked post suggests using the KOMA-Script class `scrlttr2`.

Comment: Do you use class `letter` or `scrlttr2`? Your code snippet did not show this information. `scrlttr2` has special possibilities that `letter` has not.  So your question is still not clear. Please complete your snippet to an MWE.

Comment: `scrlttr2` is the class.

Comment: @TyquanPesik: So answer in the posted link provide solutions for typesetting what you're after in the document class that you're using (`scrlttr2`). Why does it not work for you?